# MySQL WHEN vs. WHERE in performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, where-clause

Updating multiple rows in one query, both work.

**With WHERE**

```
UPDATE category
    SET description = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'good'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'bad'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'ugly'
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

**Without WHERE**

```
UPDATE category
    SET description = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'good'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'bad'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'ugly'
    END
```

But what's the difference? Does `WHEN` use indexes? Which is preferable in terms of performance when the table grows very large?

Comment: Reformulate as a SELECT and use EXPLAIN to check if indexes are used.

Comment: In your "without WHERE", what happens when id = 4 ? Is "id" always defined, and equal to one the three values ?

Comment: @DanielSchneller, can you please help me reformulate it as a SELECT? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `WHERE` reduces the data set you work with. `WHERE` and `WHEN` have no place in the same sentence as they do totally different things. First query operates on a maximum of 3 records while the second query operates on ALL records. I think the difference is clear. `WHEN` doesn't use indexes. It's  impossible for `WHEN` to use indexes because you're just checking a value of a column against the data set that you have selected. Also, it appears you're not totally clear on *what* indexes do and what they don't do. Indexes are not some magic beast that makes stuff work fast if you just set an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Your two queries are quite different.  The first will affect only rows that have the three values for `id`.  The second will affect all rows, setting the description to `NULL` for rows that have any other value for `id`.  To be equivalent, the second query should be:

```
UPDATE category
    SET description = (CASE id
                           WHEN 1 THEN 'good'
                           WHEN 2 THEN 'bad'
                           WHEN 3 THEN 'ugly'
                           ELSE description
                       END);
```

These two queries are still semantically different, although the effect on the data is the same.  For instance, this version would call an `update` trigger on all rows, whereas the first version would only call it on rows that match the `WHERE` condition.

You should use the `WHERE` condition, if you care about performance and maintainability of the query.